# IE addon works well in development machine but not in test machines

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, bho, ieaddon

IE addon works well in development machine but in test machines I am installing it as an msi. The addon(The browser extension and the BHO) gets created successfully and gets listed in manage addons. But on clicking the addon it doesnot work (setsite() is not called)

Comment: Could you show us a sample with screenshots and/or code ?

Comment: May I know what type of screenshots will help u